# why am I getting compile error when trying to copy data from master sheet to multiple worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I am very new to VBA and macros so I apologise if this is simple.  I have found similar posts but nothing that I am able to adjust to my problem.  I found code to create a new worksheet for every new entry in a list in my workbook which works well.  I would like to have every row on the master sheet copied into the appropriate tab created in the macro above if the value in column BT matches the name of the new worksheet.  I found the following code which I thought I had adjusted correctly but I am getting a 'compile error - sub or function not defined' when I run it. my master sheet is called 'final' and column BT contains the value that matches the other worksheet names.  My understanding of the -71 is that it is the number of columns to the left of the column that is being referenced.

```
Sub copyPasteData()
 Dim strSourceSheet As String
 Dim strDestinationSheet As String
 Dim lastRow As Long

strSourceSheet = "final"

Sheets(strSourceSheet).Visible = True
 Sheets(strSourceSheet).Select

Range("BT3").Select
 Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
 strDestinationSheet = ActiveCell.Value
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, -71).Resize(1, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Visible = True
 Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Select
 lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn("A")
 Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Sheets(strSourceSheet).Select
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
 Loop
 End Sub
```

Each month I will need to paste new data over the master sheet and would like the other worksheets to change to match.  Grateful for any help that will save me having to filter many times and copy paste into each tab.  I have used both 2007 and 2010 tags as I have to be able to run it in both.

Comment: When you get the error, if you click on the `Debug` button, which line of code does it show as having an issue?

Answer (score 0):

`lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn("A")`
Replace the above line, I think LastRowInOneColumn is not a defined function, with

`lastRow = Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row`
It gives you the last row in column A

Comment: Hi Thank you for this.  I changed that row and now I am getting a run time error '1004' on the line  - Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select.  I apologise for not knowing but I am desperate to get this piece of work finished today.

Comment: Try this `Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select `     Maybe your data is too long

Comment: If the above line did not work follow this link it explains the error 1004  `http://www.runtimeerrorsfix.com/how-to-fix-runtime-error-1004.html `

Comment: Thank you @SuperSam I followed the link but cant work out how to fix it in my excel.  I cant see the tools|Macros|Security area.

Comment: If you have Excel 2007 and higher, enter Excel Options (Office Button or File), Trust Center, Trust Center Settings

Comment: Hi @SuperSam,  I have now marked vba as trusted and rerun the code but I am now getting "runtime 1004 error Application-defined or object-defined error" - on a previous line in the code - 'ActiveCell.Offset(0, -71).Resize(1, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Select'.  research into this error seems to suggest that I need to define something but I am not sure what or how.

Comment: Try using a different method for select, instead of  `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -71).Resize(1, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Select `     write      `Range("A3:B3").Select `   for example

Comment: Thank you @SuperSam - there is now data being copied however it is copying it all to the last tab which happens to be named the same as the value that is currently in BT6.  I am sure the problem is in the area <strSourceSheet = "final"
Sheets(strSourceSheet).Visible = True
 Sheets(strSourceSheet).Select
Range("BT6").Select
 Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
 strDestinationSheet = ActiveCell.Value
Range("A5:BT1000").Select> It is copying everything in A5toBT100 and pasting into the tabname in BT6 - how do I get it to paste to the relevant tab name in each cell listed in column BT>

Comment: your destination sheet should vary, you have to assign the ranges where you have the name of destination sheets, it should read one selection and write in the corresponding sheet